# ErlIDE and console output support

Tags: erlide

How can I view my io:format(…) output in ErlIDE? Is it supported or not? I can't figure it out.

My breakpoints and a code work fine but nothing except

```
Eshell V5.9.1
(erlhttp@ONIXNB)1>
```

is displayed on the console. Additionally I can't execute any code in an code input window below the console; when I press *Ctrl+Enter* it just wraps a line.

Manual **erl** launch shows me everything I printed in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need additional information to tell you what happens for you.

I have this code

```
-module(y).
-compile(export_all).
f() ->
    F = oki,
    io:format("format ~p~n", [F]),
    F.
```

and in the console

```
Eshell V5.9.1.1
(main@eselnts1104.mo.sw.ericsson.se)1> y:f().
format oki
oki
```

Please send me the logs (at https://www.assembla.com/spaces/erlide/support/tickets, for example, I don't know if you can attach them here). Logs are retrieved from window->preferences->erlang->report problem.

Comment: Nice to see you here, Vlad. :) I've created a ticket https://www.assembla.com/spaces/erlide/support/tickets/1073-console-output-problem

Comment: Now I have reinstalled the latest erlide beta and my question is closed. It does support the console input and output. Details are in the ticket. Thanks to Vladimir.